# Bootstrap select live search input when change will extract values

Tags: javascript, api, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-select

I'm trying to add an option on my select input coming from an API JSON Response. and I'm currently using Bootstrap 4 and Bootstrap-select
i was able to find the liveSearchListener: function together with this.$searchbox.on('input propertychange' but when i'm putting a function to add an option. my function is not working and option items are not added.

Can anyone help?
Thank you so much!

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: Sure will edit my answer below

Answer (score 0):

First you need to download the bootstrap-select.js file
here
https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/

then search for this text without quotation.

"**this.$searchbox.on('input propertychange', function ()**"

this line execute when the value of the inputbox of the live search changes.
I created a function that will pass the current value of the inputbox from this line, you can get the current value of the text box by referencing on below text

*passes the value of searchbox of live search to a variable.*

**var searchValue = that.$searchbox.val();**

*function is called and pass the current value of the live search box*

**selectfiller(searchValue);**

while calling the function that fills the input select you need to refresh the list by putting
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');
after you added all of the items